# How do I remove a customiser option from a parent theme in a child theme?

Tags: customization, child-theme, theme-customizer

Let's say there is a theme that you like but you want to make some changes. You make a child-theme. At least you do if you follow good advice. So now you have a child theme. You are happy with it and want to share. There is just one small problem - one of the controls in the customizer makes no-sense with the changes you have made.

How do you make the customizer control from the parent theme go away for your child theme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/):

> To add, remove, or modify any Customizer object, and to access the
>   Customizer Manager, use the
>   [customize_register](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_register/)
>   hook:
>
> ```
> function themeslug_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
>   // Do stuff with $wp_customize, the WP_Customize_Manager object.
> }
> add_action( 'customize_register', 'themeslug_customize_register' );
> ```
>
> The Customizer Manager provides add_, get_, and remove_ methods for
>   each Customizer object type; each works with an id. The get_ methods
>   allow for direct modification of parameters specified when adding a
>   control.
>
> ```
> add_action('customize_register','my_customize_register');
> function my_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
>   $wp_customize->add_panel();
>   $wp_customize->get_panel();
>   $wp_customize->remove_panel();
>
>   $wp_customize->add_section();
>   $wp_customize->get_section();
>   $wp_customize->remove_section();
>
>   $wp_customize->add_setting();
>   $wp_customize->get_setting();
>   $wp_customize->remove_setting();
>
>   $wp_customize->add_control();
>   $wp_customize->get_control();
>   $wp_customize->remove_control();
> }
> ```

So in your case, you can remove a *control* using [`WP_Customize_Manager::remove_control()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/remove_control/).

Example for the Twenty Nineteen theme:

```
function my_theme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    // Remove the Colors -> Primary Color option.
    $wp_customize->remove_control( 'primary_color' );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'my_theme_customize_register', 11 );
```